# Adding prefix path to static files in Angular using angular-cli

Tags: javascript, django, angular, typescript, angular-cli

I have an existing django project where I am serving static files over /static/ path. I am migrating a part of the application to angular2, to be specific mobile version of the site.

Adding `<base href="/">` to index.html loads static files www.example.com/main.js gets 404 here.
Adding `<base href="/static/">` to index.html loads static files correctly, but when the application bootstraps, it changes the url to /static/ (i am using routers), although my url should be /order/.

is there a way of using base href as / but adding prefix to script and style files using angular-cli

using version `ng --version`

```
@angular/cli: 1.0.0-rc.0
node: 6.9.1
os: win32 x64
@angular/common: 2.4.9
@angular/compiler: 2.4.9
@angular/core: 2.4.9
@angular/forms: 2.4.9
@angular/http: 2.4.9
@angular/platform-browser: 2.4.9
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 2.4.9
@angular/router: 3.4.9
@angular/cli: 1.0.0-rc.0
@angular/compiler-cli: 2.4.9
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use --deploy-url to prefix path of your generated static files. `ng build --deploy-url /static/`. It will prefix path of js files with `/static/` in generated index.html like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/inline.bundle.js"></script>
```

From help doc:

```
--deploy-url (String) URL where files will be deployed.
```

example:

```
ng build --prod --deploy-url=example.com/scripts/
```

**Updated answer based on comments.**

Comment: What about the static files in the assets ?

Comment: Yes, `-d` is not valid command, so `--deploy-url` is the only one.

Comment: How about images ? if i do that with base href , it will add prefix to all routes

Answer (score 2):

Using angular CLI 6.1.1

This how I do it, you need to use the build flag `--base-href`

**Example**

```
ng build --prod --base-href=/dist/my-app/
```

and I access the site like this `http://127.0.0.1:5500/dist/my-app/index.html`

Official document reference [here](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#simplest-deployment-possible)

Comment: This is not what OP is looking for, this just changes `href` in `<base href="/">`.